# Opencv CAMshift tracking quality

Tags: opencv, video-tracking

I have using camshift method from python opencv to track the object after the detection,does it anyway to stop tracking when the object move out of the screen? Does it provide a function if the tracking quality below some threshold then it will discard the tracking?